# How to create a hashmap in java class

Tags: java, class, hashmap

This is my code. My intention is create a hashmap with 4 values, then export this class as a jar, add it to another project,  and use the hashmap values there.

I'm getting error in all the "hmap.put". I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class MyFirstClass {

    private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    hmap.put(2, "Jane");
    hmap.put(4, "John");
    hmap.put(3, "Klay");
    hmap.put(1, "Deena");

    public HashMap<Integer, String> gethmap()
   {
        return this.hmap;
   }

    public void sethmap(HashMap hmap)
   {
        this.hmap = hmap;
   }

   }
```

Comment: use a constructor

Comment: You can't put statements like `hmap.put(...)` directly inside a class. They must be inside a method or a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyFirstClass {

    private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {

        {
            hmap.put(4, "John");
            hmap.put(3, "Klay");
            hmap.put(1, "Deena");
        }
    };

    public HashMap<Integer, String> gethmap() {
        return this.hmap;
    }

    public void sethmap(HashMap<Integer, String> hmap) {
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }

}
```

Above code will help you to get the result which you desire. You should also note that you can not use instance variable directly inside class. you have to use that inside method only.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't allow executing any statements outside of the scope of any method, field initialization or static block - that's why you get an error.

I suppose, your intent is to do some initialization with that four lines. And Java has support for such kind of initialization - it is the class constructor. So the proper code would look like the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyFirstClass {
  private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  // this is a constructor
  public MyFirstClass() {
    hmap.put(2, "Jane");
    hmap.put(4, "John");
    hmap.put(3, "Klay");
    hmap.put(1, "Deena");
  }

  // here goes your other code
}
```

This way every object of MyFirstClass you create using `new MyFirstClass()` will contain the data you put in the constructor.

You can read more about the constructors in Java in the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: how does putting the hmap.put statements in constructor differ from putting it all in main method ?

Comment: @NGB it's a sort of encapsulation - this way you see the initial data of the object in the same class, while your main method may be in some other class

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. Easiest one is to just add brackets to your put statements:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyFirstClass {
    private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    {
        hmap.put(2, "Jane");
        hmap.put(4, "John");
        hmap.put(3, "Klay");
        hmap.put(1, "Deena");
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, String> gethmap() {
        return this.hmap;
    }

    public void sethmap(HashMap hmap) {
        this.hmap = hmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of gethmap()  and  sethmap() ?

Comment: You can use these methods to set and get your hmap.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to your class:

```
public MyFirstClass() {
    this.hmap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    // you can do .put here if you wish
}
```

And change the `hmap` field to:

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap;
```

Comment: Actually, it's pretty possible and even convenient to do this king of field initialization directly, not in the constructor.

Comment: I know, but I prefer to instantiate inside the constructor. It's really a question of personal taste (:

Answer (score 1):

You're using a method outside of a method. You cannot call Hashmap.put within the class but outside the method - as was mentioned you want to do that in the constructor of the class

```
public class MyFirstClass {
    public MyFirstClass() { //put it here }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a static block, just as:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> NAME_MAP = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    {
        NAME_MAP.put(2, "Jane");
        NAME_MAP.put(4, "John");
        NAME_MAP.put(3, "Klay");
        NAME_MAP.put(1, "Deena");
    }
};
```

Comment: This won't compile at all.  Did you mean to have a static clause?

Comment: Where do you see the point in creating a subclass of `HashMap`?

Comment: @Tom It's using java 8 then, because this won't compile with java 7.

Comment: @Neil it is possible to make a block without `static` keyword - it is called an initializer block: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: @Neil It's compiling in Java 7 for me at least

Comment: @Tom what do you mean, it's not a subclass of HashMap as you can see I do ``new HashMap``

Comment: Beware you can't use diamond operator in this case

Comment: @Neil No, there aren't any Java 8 features here, I guess you're just using the code snippet wrong. As you can see here http://ideone.com/zjAyZG you can compile it (and run it if you fix the initializer block).

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from new HashMap<Integer,String>(){} to Map<Integer,String>`  You had to change type of NAME_MAP before it compiled I assume?

Comment: @Vixen What do you think what `new HashMap<Integer, String>() { ... }` does? Since you may don't know it: [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Ah, no, I know why now.  HashMap wasn't imported yet, but rather than giving a *sane* error...